# Gong drag and drop: Can't copy from treeview to listbox

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, listbox, treeview

I have the following classes:

```
public class VM_AssetPack : INotifyPropertyChanged, IHasAttributeGroupMenu, IDropTarget, IHasSubgroupViewModels
{
   public ObservableCollection<VM_Subgroup> Subgroups { get; set; }
}

public class VM_Subgroup : INotifyPropertyChanged, ICloneable, IDropTarget, IHasSubgroupViewModels
{
    public ObservableCollection<VM_Subgroup> RequiredSubgroups { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<VM_Subgroup> ExcludedSubgroups { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<VM_Subgroup> Subgroups { get; set; }
}
```

The VM_AssetPack's subgroups are displayed in a treeview bound to the Subgroups property. The VM_Subgroup's Required/Excluded Subgroups are displayed in a ListBox. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpNel.jpg) is a screenshot of the layout. [Here](https://github.com/Synthesis-Collective/SynthEBD) is the project Git repository (I haven't yet pushed my latest changes to the drag & drop). I would like to implement the following behavior:

Drag from treeview to treeview via left click: Move subgroup to drop target's Subgroups
Drag from treeview to treeview via right click: Copy subgroup to drop target's Subgroups
Drag from treeview to listbox via any click: Copy subgroup to drop target's R/E Subgroups.

I currently have the treeview drag and drop working as desired.
Xaml (UserControl_AssetPack):

```
<TreeView Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Name="TVsubgroups"  ItemsSource ="{Binding Subgroups}"  Margin="0 0 15 0" dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True" dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True" dd:DragDrop.DropHandler="{Binding}"  dd:DragDrop.CanDragWithMouseRightButton="True">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:VM_Subgroup}" ItemsSource="{Binding Subgroups}" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Margin="5 0 5 0" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="HandleSelectPreviewMouseDown" MouseLeftButtonUp="HandleSelectPreviewMouseUp">
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}">
                            <Binding Path="Name"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectedSubgroupChanged}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TVsubgroups, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TreeView>

ContentPresenter Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1"  Content="{Binding ElementName=TVsubgroups, Path=SelectedItem}" Name="SubgroupPresenter">
    <ContentPresenter.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:VM_Subgroup}">
            <local:UC_Subgroup Background="Black" Margin="0 0 0 10"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentPresenter.Resources>
</ContentPresenter>
```

View Model (VM_AssetPack):

```
public bool DropInitiatedRightClick { get; set; }

public void DragOver(IDropInfo dropInfo)
{
    if (dropInfo.Data is VM_Subgroup)
    {
        dropInfo.DropTargetAdorner = DropTargetAdorners.Highlight;
        dropInfo.Effects = DragDropEffects.Move;
        if (dropInfo.KeyStates.HasFlag(DragDropKeyStates.RightMouseButton))
        {
            DropInitiatedRightClick = true;
        }
    }
}

public void Drop(IDropInfo dropInfo)
{
    if (dropInfo.Data is VM_Subgroup && (dropInfo.TargetItem is IHasSubgroupViewModels || dropInfo.TargetItem is ObservableCollection<VM_Subgroup>))
    {
        var draggedSubgroup = (VM_Subgroup)dropInfo.Data;
        var clone = (VM_Subgroup)draggedSubgroup.Clone();
        if (dropInfo.TargetItem is VM_Subgroup)
        {
            VM_Subgroup dropTarget = (VM_Subgroup)dropInfo.TargetItem;

            if (dropTarget.Name == draggedSubgroup.Name && dropTarget.ID == draggedSubgroup.ID) { return; }

            clone.ParentCollection = dropTarget.Subgroups;
            clone.ParentAssetPack = dropTarget.ParentAssetPack;
            dropTarget.Subgroups.Add(clone);
        }
        else if (dropInfo.TargetItem is VM_AssetPack)
        {
            VM_AssetPack dropTarget = (VM_AssetPack)dropInfo.TargetItem;
            clone.ParentCollection = dropTarget.Subgroups;
            clone.ParentAssetPack = dropTarget;
            dropTarget.Subgroups.Add(clone);
        }

        if (!DropInitiatedRightClick)
        {
            draggedSubgroup.ParentCollection.Remove(draggedSubgroup);
        }
    }

    DropInitiatedRightClick = false;
}
```

This allows me to drag and drop within the treeview as described above (although it does not allow me to drag a nested inner subgroup leaf to the top level of the treeview, or to rearrange the order of leaves at the nodes - if someone could help me enable this I'd appreciate it). The main problem I'm having is with the listboxes though:

Xaml (UserControl_Subgroup):

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="15" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding RequiredSubgroups}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True" dd:DragDrop.DropHandler="{Binding}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}:{1}">
                            <Binding Path="ID" />
                            <Binding Path="Name" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

<ListBox Grid.Row="16" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ExcludedSubgroups}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True" dd:DragDrop.DragDropCopyKeyState="None">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}:{1}">
                            <Binding Path="ID" />
                            <Binding Path="Name" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

View Model (VM_Subgroup):

```
public object Clone()
{
    return this.MemberwiseClone();
}

public void DragOver(IDropInfo dropInfo)
{
    if (dropInfo.Data is VM_Subgroup)
    {
        dropInfo.DropTargetAdorner = DropTargetAdorners.Highlight;
        dropInfo.Effects = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }
}

public void Drop(IDropInfo dropInfo)
{
    if (dropInfo.Data is VM_Subgroup)
    {
        var draggedSubgroup = (VM_Subgroup)dropInfo.Data;
        var newCollection = (ObservableCollection<VM_Subgroup>)dropInfo.TargetItem;
        newCollection.Add((VM_Subgroup)draggedSubgroup.Clone());
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm trying two different solutions: using my own drop handler (RequiredSubgroups) and the default handler (ExcludedSubgroups).

If I drag a subgroup from the TreeView over the RequiredSubgroups ListBox, I get an exception at `newCollection.Add`, and investigating in the debugger shows that dropInfo.TargetItem is Null. I do not understand why it is Null here.

If I drag a subgroup from the TreeView over the ExcludedSubgroups ListBox, the drop works but it always removes the subgroup from its parent in the TreeView. I've tried with and without `dd:DragDrop.DragDropCopyKeyState="None"` in both the ListBox and the TreeView, and no matter what the Subgroup disappears from the ListBox.

I'd really appreciate some help figuring out how to copy from the tree to the list without removing the original item from the tree.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't read the whole post, but to be able to copy, you have to define your preferred button instead of

```
dd:DragDrop.DragDropCopyKeyState="None".
```

I use

```
dd:DragDrop.DragDropCopyKeyState="ControlKey".
```

Greets